# React and Redux: Managing Redux Custom Middleware List

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-middleware

For my react app, I have built many custom middlewares and passed them in the `applyMiddleware()`. Because I have so many, the redux store file is looking a little congested. Is it a good practice to pass them all in the `applyMiddleware()` or import them in a separate file within a function and then pass that function in the `applyMiddleware()` to keep it clean?

```js
// Redux store
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...xMdl, ...yMdl, ...zMdl, ...nAmountsOfMdl),
  )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to make groups for reducers using combineReducers.
ill share my middleware setup, hope it's helpful for u!

store.config.js :

```
import rootReducer from '../_reducers'

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export const store = configureStore();

export default function configureStore(preloadingState) {
  const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer(history),
    preloadingState,
    composeEnhancer(
      applyMiddleware(
        routerMiddleware(history),
        thunk,
      ),
    ),
  )

  return store
}
```

index.js (in reducers folder) :

```
const rootReducer = (history) => combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    single: combineReducers({
        post: postReducer,
        guide: guideReducer,
        course: courseReducer,
        lesson: lessonReducer,
        exercise: exerciseReducer,
    }),
    bank: combineReducers({
        posts: postsReducer,
        guides: guidesReducer,
        courses: coursesReducer,
        lessons: lessonsReducer,
        exercises: exercisesReducer,
    }),
    melodition: playerReducer,
    user: combineReducers({
        profile: profileReducer,
        favorites: favoriteReducer,
    }),
    snackbar: snackbarReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Note: I did this on a large project with [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router), maybe it's not good for every project.

Comment: Thank you. Nice to see what others are doing. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Also, my get custom api middle is firing but not my delete. How do you approach the custom delete api middleware?

Comment: no problem happy to help u ,can u share ur delete api middleware details ? did u dispatch it ? 
i have wordpress for handling sever side api, but on application to delete data from redux store an action for making new array of items, example:  `export const deletePost = (id) => ((dispatch,getState) => {const newPosts = getState().bank.posts.data.filter(post => post.id !== id);dispatch({ type: DELETE_POST, newPosts })})`